# Compiler Error: Method cant be applied to types(Factorial Program)

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Im new to Java and im frequently getting this error.
Here is the error:

Factorial.java:17: error: method factorialLoop in class Factorial cannot be applied to given types;

factorialLoop();

^

required: int

found: no arguments

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length****

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Factorial
 {
  public static void main(String [] args)
   {
       int factVariable;
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter an integer to calculate its factorial.");
       factVariable = sc.nextInt();
       int fact = factorialLoop(factVariable);
       if(factVariable < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Number, must be non-negative.");
        }
       else
        {
            factorialLoop();
        }
       System.out.println("Factorial of " + factVariable + "is = " + fact);
   }
  public static int factorialLoop(int factVariable)
   {
       int fact = 1;
       for(int i = 1; i <= factVariable; i++)
        {
            fact = fact * i;
        }
   }
 }
```

The aim of this program is to calculate the factorial and this is the last error im getting thats stopping me from compiling. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you need to define a method with a given set of arguments to call it with those arguments. `factorialLoop();` is not a method that you have defined. In java, you can have multiple methods with the same name, but with different arguments. This is a principal known as overloading. Despite this, the methods need to individually be defined. As such, you either need to define a `factorialLoop();` method or you will need to change that piece of code to something like `factorialLoop();`. After you fix this, you will also run into an error in your factorialLoop method because you need to add a return statement (since the method specifies that it needs to return a value).

Since you are just starting out with Java, I recommend checking out an IDE such as [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), as it will help you quickly find out and fix compile time errors.

Answer (score 0):

1) Firstly there is no method implementation named factorialLoop() without argument.

2) return type for the method is also not correct.

3) Try below that might help. I have used recursion and removed first call to function factorialLoop();

```
import java.util.*;
public class Factorial
  {
   public static void main(String [] args)
    {
      int factVariable;
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter an integer to calculate its factorial.");
      factVariable = sc.nextInt(); 


      if(factVariable < 0)
      {
         System.out.println("Invalid Number, must be non-negative.");
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("Factorial of " + factVariable + " is = "
        +   factorialLoop(factVariable));
      }

    }
    public static int factorialLoop(int n)
    {
       if (n == 1)      
          return 1;      
        else      
          return(n * factorialLoop(n-1));    
    }
  }
```